# Navigation buttons for pages that lists of searched items

Tags: html, css, button, navigation

I am learning HTML5 and designing a website.
My website lists items but when I click on the navigation buttons, (page number, 1, 2, next, previous)
It opens a blank page.

How can I make it work that when I click on the button "2" it will open next page of searched items.
Thanks

Comment: Are you only learning HTML and CSS or are you allowed to use JavaScript? Because if it is just HTML + CSS you'll need to manually set the `href` of an anchor element. `<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.